# "Hang In The Main Graphics Engine"

Tags: performance, graphics, gpu, kernel

Mac: MacBook Pro, mid2012, 9,1 Core i7 2.3Ghz, 16 GB RAM, 1TB SSD, nVidia 650M, IntelHD 4000

I use several macOS systems incl. the default one - Lion. 2 weeks ago slowdowns began to occur - apps slow to launch (even such lightweight ones as Console), Finder crashes, icons bouncing off the Dock - something that was never the case during the 7 years that I own it. I don't see visual artefacts, graphic mess: I can play video, and do usual stuff but every 2-3 days, at some point Mac becomes very sluggish and only restarting helps. Between these hangs, Mac is fast and robust (as robust as 7 years old machine can be). Every time this happens Lion's Console shows this repeating message:

```sql
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: ****  Debug info for *possible* hang in MAIN graphics engine  ****
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: VRSYNC: (0x12044) = 0xe535d
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: BRSYNC: (0x22040) = 0x0
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: RVSYNC: (0x 2040) = 0x0
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: BVSYNC: (0x22044) = 0x0
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: RBSYNC: (0x 2044) = 0x0
25/02/2021 11:46:17.000 kernel: VBSYNC: (0x12040) = 0x0
25/02/2021 11:46:22.000 kernel: stampWait: Overflowed checking for stamp 0xe5377 on MAIN ring: called from
```

No issues with external monitors. I had it repaired 2 weeks ago (an audio speaker).

In the other macOS systems, Console doesn't produce these messages: I don't have this behaviour erupting there but I noticed messages about some "GPU dump" in Mojave. Is the GPU dying?

Comment: Does the same happen in safe mode?

Comment: It happens not often enough to justify starting in safe mode: several days or more can pass before it may occur.

Comment: You said `I had it repaired 2 weeks ago (an audio speaker)` and `2 weeks ago slowdowns began to occur`. Can you confirm that these slowdowns only started happening **after** repair?

Comment: No, it can be a coincidence. I can't tell for sure, I have no evidence. It could well start because I began using some graphic intensive software more than I used to.